# Glide - Cannot stop gif onClick- Getting TransitionDrawable instead of Animate/GifDrawable

Tags: android, imageview, gif, android-glide

I am loading gif image in Imageview with container recyclerview.
Currently the recyclerview has only 1 gif and other are bitmaps.
I am loading gif as

```
Glide.with(context).
load("https://media.giphy.com/media/TcKmUDTdICRwY/giphy.gif").
asGif().
override(params.width, params.height).
diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT).
placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder).
error(R.drawable.error).
listener(new RequestListener<Uri, GifDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, Uri model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                 return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GifDrawable resource, Uri model, Target<GifDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
               resource.stop(); //Stoping gif animation on complete download
                return false;
               }
        }).
        into(feed.imgFeed);
```

I want on Demand gif loading i.e When gif image is completely downloaded i don't want to start it on it's own rather when user clicks it.
In click event i am checking drawable instance if it's Animated/GifDrawable to start the animation.
But i am receiving TransitionDrawable that does not allow animation.

Comment: have you find the solution ? If not then let me know I can help you.

Comment: Thanks, Got the solution

Comment: I also did with some trick , I also need neat and clean solution. Can you help me on this.

Comment: @ohm you should post the solution, may be someone else facing this situation. like here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37438197/set-gif-image-to-custom-imageview

Comment: Yeah, I can't able to show image from raw directory

Comment: @DevendraSingh I did same as hardik  http://stackoverflow.com/a/36975690/1488066

Comment: @Komal i commented your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an alternative approach :

- Use `.diskCacheStrategy(SOURCE)` to have fast GIF display.
- Once you  have `SOURCE` cache you can display the image with `.asBitmap()` forcing the first frame to be displayed.
- `SOURCE` will also make sure when loading the first frame and the animation the file won't be downloaded twice.
- In `onClick` load the same image with different params, that is `.asGif()` to "start the animation" this saves a lot of memory and processing if you have multiple `GIFs`.

Here us code :

```
final Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://media.giphy.com/media/TcKmUDTdICRwY/giphy.gif");
final BitmapRequestBuilder<Uri, GlideDrawable> thumbRequest = Glide
        .with(context)
        .load(uri)
        .asBitmap() // force first frame for Gif
        .transcode(new BitmapToGlideDrawableTranscoder(context), GlideDrawable.class)
        .override(params.width, params.height)
        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
        .error(R.drawable.image_error)
        .fitCenter();

thumbRequest.into(feed.imgFeed);

feed.imgFeed.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { 
    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        Glide
                .with(context)
                .load(uri) // load as usual (Gif as animated, other formats as Bitmap)
                .override(params.width, params.height)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
                .error(R.drawable.image_error)
                .thumbnail(thumbRequest)
                .dontAnimate()
                .into(feed.imgFeed);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok

I had to change the steps to load gifs as even loading first frame was taking much time and was taking 1 mb data (arbitary value) so user would waste 5 mb just to load frame of 5 gifs.
Hence changed the flow,taking 2 image version from server

1. Gif,Actual image
2. First frame of Gif,100 kb Max

Loading Gif on image click works and saves data as well.

Comment: How do you get the first frame of a GIF? I don't see any API of Glide could do this.

Comment: First frame of gif was actually a Bitmap image.I used two image versions one was this static bitmap and other was actual GIF.

Comment: I mean, is there a way to intercept it and force the Glide to decode the first frame only? I only see the `asBitmap` and `DiskStrategy.RESULT` can do this. But if I put my picture(PNG, JPEG) displays in different sizes, it will download it again because of the `DiskStrategy.RESULT` option tells the Glide to only stores the resized file cache. How did you split these two flows on demand?

Comment: `asBitmap` helps decoding first frame, why is it that the image size is changing?Can you provide me your code gist?

Comment: Because my user can click the image to watch it in full size. The image in the `RecyclerView` is just for previewing.

Comment: I am doing the same, maintaining the aspect ratio `.override(params.width, params.height)` so size doesn't change