# Set GIF image to Custom ImageView

Tags: android, animated-gif

I have custom ImageView for animated GIF image. i want to show GIF image, I tried but in this case it is contain url in Async instead I want to show GIF image from raw folder without using Glide. Anyone have any idea how to show image? Please guyz help to solve this problem!!!

I tried this for set raw file

```
 new GifStaticData() {
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Resource drawable) {
                super.onPostExecute(drawable);
                gifImageView.setImageResource(R.raw.earth_tilt_animation);
//                Log.d(TAG, "GIF width is " + gifImageView.getGifWidth());
               // Log.d(TAG, "GIF height is " + gifImageView.getGifHeight());
            }

        }.execute(R.raw.earth_tilt_animation);
```

GifStaticData.java

```
public class GifStaticData extends AsyncTask<Resource, Void, Resource> {
  private static final String TAG = "GifDataDownloader";

  @Override protected Resource doInBackground(final Resource... params) {
    final Resource gifUrl = params[0];

    if (gifUrl == null)
      return null;

    try {
//      return ByteArrayHttpClient.get(gifUrl);
      return gifUrl;
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
      Log.e(TAG, "GifDecode OOM: " + gifUrl, e);
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

GifImageView.java

```
public class GifImageView extends ImageView implements Runnable {

  private static final String TAG = "GifDecoderView";
  private GifDecoder gifDecoder;
  private Bitmap tmpBitmap;
  private final Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
  private boolean animating;
  private boolean shouldClear;
  private Thread animationThread;
  private OnFrameAvailable frameCallback = null;
  private long framesDisplayDuration = -1L;
  private OnAnimationStop animationStopCallback = null;

  private final Runnable updateResults = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      if (tmpBitmap != null && !tmpBitmap.isRecycled()) {
        setImageBitmap(tmpBitmap);
      }
    }
  };

  private final Runnable cleanupRunnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
      tmpBitmap = null;
      gifDecoder = null;
      animationThread = null;
      shouldClear = false;
    }
  };

  public GifImageView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
  }

  public GifImageView(final Context context) {
    super(context);
  }

  public void setBytes(final byte[] bytes) {
    gifDecoder = new GifDecoder();
    try {
      gifDecoder.read(bytes);
      gifDecoder.advance();
    } catch (final OutOfMemoryError e) {
      gifDecoder = null;
      Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
      return;
    }

    if (canStart()) {
      animationThread = new Thread(this);
      animationThread.start();
    }
  }

  public long getFramesDisplayDuration() {
    return framesDisplayDuration;
  }

  /**
   * Sets custom display duration in milliseconds for the all frames. Should be called before {@link
   * #startAnimation()}
   *
   * @param framesDisplayDuration Duration in milliseconds. Default value = -1, this property will
   *                              be ignored and default delay from gif file will be used.
   */
  public void setFramesDisplayDuration(long framesDisplayDuration) {
    this.framesDisplayDuration = framesDisplayDuration;
  }

  public void startAnimation() {
    animating = true;

    if (canStart()) {
      animationThread = new Thread(this);
      animationThread.start();
    }
  }

  public boolean isAnimating() {
    return animating;
  }

  public void stopAnimation() {
    animating = false;

    if (animationThread != null) {
      animationThread.interrupt();
      animationThread = null;
    }
  }

  public void clear() {
    animating = false;
    shouldClear = true;
    stopAnimation();
    handler.post(cleanupRunnable);
  }

  private boolean canStart() {
    return animating && gifDecoder != null && animationThread == null;
  }

  public int getGifWidth() {
    return gifDecoder.getWidth();
  }

  public int getGifHeight() {
    return gifDecoder.getHeight();
  }

  @Override public void run() {
    if (shouldClear) {
      handler.post(cleanupRunnable);
      return;
    }

    final int n = gifDecoder.getFrameCount();
    do {
      for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (!animating) {
          break;
        }
        //milliseconds spent on frame decode
        long frameDecodeTime = 0;
        try {
          long before = System.nanoTime();
          tmpBitmap = gifDecoder.getNextFrame();
          frameDecodeTime = (System.nanoTime() - before) / 1000000;
          if (frameCallback != null) {
            tmpBitmap = frameCallback.onFrameAvailable(tmpBitmap);
          }

          if (!animating) {
            break;
          }
          handler.post(updateResults);
        } catch (final ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
          Log.w(TAG, e);
        }
        if (!animating) {
          break;
        }
        gifDecoder.advance();
        try {
          int delay = gifDecoder.getNextDelay();
          // Sleep for frame duration minus time already spent on frame decode
          // Actually we need next frame decode duration here,
          // but I use previous frame time to make code more readable
          delay -= frameDecodeTime;
          if (delay > 0) {
            Thread.sleep(framesDisplayDuration > 0 ? framesDisplayDuration : delay);
          }
        } catch (final Exception e) {
          // suppress any exception
          // it can be InterruptedException or IllegalArgumentException
        }
      }
    } while (animating);
    if (animationStopCallback != null) {
      animationStopCallback.onAnimationStop();
    }
  }

  public OnFrameAvailable getOnFrameAvailable() {
    return frameCallback;
  }

  public void setOnFrameAvailable(OnFrameAvailable frameProcessor) {
    this.frameCallback = frameProcessor;
  }

  public interface OnFrameAvailable {
    Bitmap onFrameAvailable(Bitmap bitmap);
  }

  public OnAnimationStop getOnAnimationStop() {
    return animationStopCallback;
  }

  public void setOnAnimationStop(OnAnimationStop animationStop) {
    this.animationStopCallback = animationStop;
  }

  public interface OnAnimationStop {
    void onAnimationStop();
  }

  @Override
  protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
    clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: _Glide_ provides  a **GIF** animation support too then why don't want to use it.

Comment: I know but i want to start and stop animation on click on view so I can't use the Glide

Comment: Any idea about start and stop gif image expect glide

Comment: Did u check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12406540/how-to-start-and-stop-gif-images-in-android??

Comment: Yeah.. I have seen this but here comment is, it is not for gif. it is for png, So i didn't try

Comment: Oh okay. Now time time to go to home. You can add me on google+. Will try to solve. You can get my ID from SO profile.

Comment: Ok Thanks!!!!...........

Answer (score 0):

I had to play and pause the Gif image [Glide - Cannot stop gif onClick- Getting TransitionDrawable instead of Animate/GifDrawable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36061091/2606144)

The idea is to get drawable from view,checking if it is an instance of Gifdrawable and playing and pausing it.(Hoping the gif image is already playing)

Add this In OnClick of GifImageView

```
Drawable drawable = ((ImageView) v).getDrawable();
if (drawable instanceof GifDrawable) {
         GifDrawable animatable = (GifDrawable) drawable;
         if (animatable.isRunning()) {
                 animatable.stop();
         } else {
                animatable.start();
         }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I can't able to show it, Have u any idea about of my updated code?

Comment: Where is your updated code?I can't see any ..
Are you sure you are using Glide?

Comment: I mean Have you any idea about my above code without using Glide?

Comment: No, i haven't used GifDecoder yet so can't help there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution of above problem using GifMovieView!!!

GifMovieViewer.java

```
public class GifMovieViewer extends Activity {
    private Button btnStart;
    private GifMovieView gif1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gif_movie_viewer);

        gif1 = (GifMovieView) findViewById(R.id.gif1);
        btnStart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStart);

        btnStart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                gif1.setMovieResource(R.drawable.earth_tilt_animation);
                //for pause
                // gif1.setPaused(gif1.isPaused());
            }
        });
    }

    public void onGifClick(View v) {
        GifMovieView gif = (GifMovieView) v;
        gif.setPaused(!gif.isPaused());
    }
}
```